# NewFromFD failed in nativeDecodeFileDescriptor - Android 4.4

Tags: android

I have used Android sample project ContactsList (http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/ContactsList.zip) as an example to develop contacts Activity in my app. 
It is working perfectly on all Android versions, but in Android 4.4 the contact images are not being loaded and I get the following error:

```
 NewFromFD failed in nativeDecodeFileDescriptor
```

This happens while this method is being executed:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, options);
```

and it always returns null.

To get the **fileDescriptor** itself I use this method:

```
private Bitmap loadContactPhotoThumbnail(String photoData, int imageSize) {
    if (!isAdded() || getActivity() == null) {
        return null;
    }

    AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
    try {
        Uri thumbUri;

        if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
            thumbUri = Uri.parse(photoData);
            Log.d("imageloader", photoData);
        } else {
            final Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,photoData);

            thumbUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        }

        afd = getActivity().getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(thumbUri, "r");
        Log.d("imageloader", afd.toString());

        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;

        try{
            fileDescriptor = afd.getFileDescriptor();
            Log.d("imageloader", fileDescriptor.toString());
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (fileDescriptor != null) {
            return ImageLoader.decodeSampledBitmapFromDescriptor(
                    fileDescriptor, imageSize, imageSize);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Contact photo thumbnail not found for contact " + photoData
                    + ": " + e.toString());
        }
    } finally {
        if (afd != null) {
            try {
                afd.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

and the **photoData** is the **`Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI`** taken from **`ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`**.

And here is some part of log output of the mentioned code:

```
12-09 21:15:04.683: D/ImageCache(12531): Memory cache created (size = 6554)
12-09 21:15:05.024: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - starting work
12-09 21:15:05.024: D/imageloader(12531): content://com.android.contacts/contacts/296/photo
12-09 21:15:05.034: D/imageloader(12531): {AssetFileDescriptor: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[54]} start=0 len=-1}
12-09 21:15:05.034: D/imageloader(12531): FileDescriptor[54]
12-09 21:15:05.044: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - finished work
12-09 21:15:05.044: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - starting work
12-09 21:15:05.054: D/imageloader(12531): content://com.android.contacts/contacts/300/photo
12-09 21:15:05.064: D/imageloader(12531): {AssetFileDescriptor: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[54]} start=0 len=-1}
12-09 21:15:05.064: D/imageloader(12531): FileDescriptor[54]
12-09 21:15:05.074: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - finished work
12-09 21:15:05.084: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - starting work
12-09 21:15:05.084: D/imageloader(12531): content://com.android.contacts/contacts/318/photo
12-09 21:15:05.114: D/imageloader(12531): {AssetFileDescriptor: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[54]} start=0 len=-1}
12-09 21:15:05.114: D/imageloader(12531): FileDescriptor[54]
12-09 21:15:05.114: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - finished work
12-09 21:15:05.114: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - starting work
12-09 21:15:05.114: D/imageloader(12531): content://com.android.contacts/contacts/319/photo
12-09 21:15:05.124: D/imageloader(12531): {AssetFileDescriptor: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[54]} start=0 len=-1}
12-09 21:15:05.124: D/imageloader(12531): FileDescriptor[54]
12-09 21:15:05.124: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - finished work
12-09 21:15:05.124: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - starting work
12-09 21:15:05.124: D/imageloader(12531): content://com.android.contacts/contacts/320/photo
12-09 21:15:05.144: D/imageloader(12531): {AssetFileDescriptor: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[54]} start=0 len=-1}
12-09 21:15:05.144: D/imageloader(12531): FileDescriptor[54]
12-09 21:15:05.144: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - finished work
12-09 21:15:05.144: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - starting work
12-09 21:15:05.144: D/imageloader(12531): content://com.android.contacts/contacts/302/photo
12-09 21:15:05.154: D/imageloader(12531): {AssetFileDescriptor: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[55]} start=0 len=-1}
12-09 21:15:05.154: D/imageloader(12531): FileDescriptor[55]
12-09 21:15:05.154: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - finished work
12-09 21:15:05.164: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - starting work
12-09 21:15:05.164: D/imageloader(12531): content://com.android.contacts/contacts/301/photo
12-09 21:15:05.164: D/imageloader(12531): {AssetFileDescriptor: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[55]} start=0 len=-1}
12-09 21:15:05.164: D/imageloader(12531): FileDescriptor[55]
12-09 21:15:05.174: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - finished work
12-09 21:15:05.174: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - starting work
12-09 21:15:05.174: D/imageloader(12531): content://com.android.contacts/contacts/304/photo
12-09 21:15:05.184: D/imageloader(12531): {AssetFileDescriptor: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[55]} start=0 len=-1}
12-09 21:15:05.184: D/imageloader(12531): FileDescriptor[55]
12-09 21:15:05.184: D/ImageLoader(12531): doInBackground - finished work
```

Can anybody help me with this problem, please?

Comment: Show your log with the output of the logging included in your code.

Comment: I have updated my code and included the part of log related to this part of code. Please, tell if you need me to log other variables too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem, and although I do not know what is the problem I found a solution, which works on KitKat & JellyBean (4.2.2). All you have to do is opening the file as an `InputStream` instead of a `AssetFileDescriptor`. I used this code:

```
private Bitmap loadContactPhotoThumbnail(String photoData) {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        Uri thumbUri;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            thumbUri = Uri.parse(photoData);
        } else {
            final Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    Contacts.CONTENT_URI, photoData);
            thumbUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        }

        is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(thumbUri);

        if (is != null) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It's the same code that you can find at [Display contact badge](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/display-contact-badge.html#SetURIThumbnail), the only modification is that it uses `InputStream`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution worked for me too. I have tested on Android 4.4 and Android 2.3.3 and it works fine. I think it will work on all versions between them too.

Comment: Works great except on Samsung devices (Tested on S4 and Tab 3)