# Android sample contactList, thumbnails not loading

Tags: android

I am trying to use contactList sample code downloaded from developer.android.com.
Its showing contact list but not showing contact thumbnail ?

http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

Also sometimes when i scroll Whole phone screen border shows a red flickering line.

Edit:- Found solution to thumbnail not loading. It was an issue only on android 4.4 and following solution fixed this issue.
[NewFromFD failed in nativeDecodeFileDescriptor - Android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475495/newfromfd-failed-in-nativedecodefiledescriptor-android-4-4)

But I am still getting this flickering issue. Here is stack trace.

```
08-27 00:01:15.042  19477-19477/com.example.android.contactslist D/StrictMode﹕ StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=7 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskWriteViolation: policy=2335 violation=1
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onWriteToDisk(StrictMode.java:1130)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:196)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:450)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:187)
            at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
            at com.android.server.ssrm.SSRMUtil.writeSysfs(SSRMUtil.java:135)
            at com.android.server.ssrm.CustomFrequencyManagerService.releaseCpuDvfsLock(CustomFrequencyManagerService.java:2334)
            at com.android.server.ssrm.CustomFrequencyManagerService.releaseDVFSLockLocked(CustomFrequencyManagerService.java:2029)
            at com.android.server.ssrm.CustomFrequencyManagerService.releaseDVFSLock(CustomFrequencyManagerService.java:1958)
            at android.os.ICustomFrequencyManager$Stub.onTransact(ICustomFrequencyManager.java:285)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    # via Binder call with stack:
    android.os.StrictMode$LogStackTrace
            at android.os.StrictMode.readAndHandleBinderCallViolations(StrictMode.java:1726)
            at android.os.Parcel.readExceptionCode(Parcel.java:1447)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1416)
            at android.os.ICustomFrequencyManager$Stub$Proxy.releaseDVFSLock(ICustomFrequencyManager.java:782)
            at android.os.CustomFrequencyManager$CPUDVFSControlRequest.cancelFrequencyRequestImpl(CustomFrequencyManager.java:485)
            at android.os.CustomFrequencyManager$FrequencyRequest.cancelFrequencyRequest(CustomFrequencyManager.java:223)
            at android.os.DVFSHelper.release(DVFSHelper.java:532)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.reportScrollStateChange(AbsListView.java:5456)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4888)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4605)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8149)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2140)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2295)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1622)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2565)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2243)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8357)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4778)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4644)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4202)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4256)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4225)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4336)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4233)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4393)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4202)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4256)
            at android.view.ViewRootImp
```

Comment: Found a solution to this problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475495/newfromfd-failed-in-nativedecodefiledescriptor-android-4-4

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to thumbnails not loading.

This issue was visible only on 4.4, Opening the file as an InputStream instead of a AssetFileDescriptor fixed this issue.

1) Replace original function in ContactListFragment.java with this one.

```
private Bitmap loadContactPhotoThumbnail(String photoData) {
InputStream is = null;
try {
    Uri thumbUri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        thumbUri = Uri.parse(photoData);
    } else {
        final Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                Contacts.CONTENT_URI, photoData);
        thumbUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    }

    is = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(thumbUri);

    if (is != null) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (is != null) {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
return null;
```

}

I found this solution here

[NewFromFD failed in nativeDecodeFileDescriptor - Android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475495/newfromfd-failed-in-nativedecodefiledescriptor-android-4-4)

But I have updated that answer according to updated sample code.

Flickering was due to StrictMode policy violation which is clear from stack trace. 
So to fix that follow following steps

1. Open Settings> Developer Options and scroll down a little.
2. Here you would find the Strict Mode option.
3. Just uncheck/unmark it.
4. And, then reboot your device.